# CSS and Javascript - multiple transforms with translate and scale

Tags: css

I have a situation where I need to do multiple transforms like this:

`transform: translate(50%, 51%) scale(1,1);`

When a person scrolls the webpage, I am using javascript to modify the values of `translate(50%,51%)` to another value.  However, if I mouse over an element, I want CSS to modify the scale to `scale(1.1,1.1)` while preserving whatever translate value javascript has set.

The reason I want to do this is because I want javascript to control the `translate` to achieve a parallax effect.  But I find the javascript onmouseenter and onmouseleave events to not fire "smoothly" enough, and hence, i want to use CSS :hover to take care of the scaling.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML markup? You could consider adding another wrapper, which handles the translating, while the main element only does the scaling

Comment: @KeesvanLierop I can introduce another wrapper.  But thinking of it as a last resort.

Comment: You can not have the value for one CSS property come from two different places - it is either what you specified in your stylesheet, _or_ what you set via JS. An additional wrapper is the easiest solution. Add it via JS, if you think it would bloat your markup too much.

Comment: By splitting it up I think that would be performance wise and flexibility wise better than calculating the rendered value by JavaScript.

Comment: Ok I did as both of you have suggested.  I went and added a wrapper and apply my css zoom to the wrapper.  Thanks